# How to get other users messages from the Group where I'm an admin?

Tags: yammer

When doing API-calls on this URL

`https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/in_group/<<GROUPID>>.json?access_token=<<ACCESSTOKEN>>`

we receive posts from all users, but all of them (except Admin) are replaced via following text:
"To view this message, please update your app. If you're using the most recent version already, please view this message on the web."

Is there any work around? Will submission to App Directory help with it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post about how to fix this issue: 
https://developer.yammer.com/blog/external-messaging-developer-update

Below is the part that will unblock you:

"To get access to the new API format you need to provide the header yammer-capabilities: external-messaging when making requests to the Yammer API"